# Necessary condition for a function to be odd

Tags: real-analysis, integration, even-and-odd-functions

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that it holds
$$\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=0\qquad \forall a\in\mathbb R^+.$$

Is it true then that the function $f$ is odd, i.e. $f(x)=-f(-x)?$

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, yes.

Comment: A counterexample for noncontinuous functions: $f(x)=0$ if $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb N$ and $f(n)=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can be proven for continuous functions? By contaddition?

Answer (score 1):

First, let us define the following function:
$$F(a)=\int_{-a}^af(x)dx\qquad \forall a\in\mathbb R^+.$$
If $f$ is continuous $F$ is well defined and we can take the derivative, because of the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$F'(a)=f(a)+f(-a)$$

But, by hypothesis we have $F\equiv 0$, so $F'\equiv 0$ and then $f(a)+f(-a)=0~\forall~a\in\mathbb{R}^+$, so $f$ is odd.

If $f$ is not continuous @TitoEliatron gave you a counterexample, so the result is not true.

In fact $f$ is 'almost odd' (is odd in all $\mathbb{R}$ but a set of measure $0$). To correct this and have the result for all $\mathbb{R}$ you need $f$ to be continuous.